# Can Pearson Correlation be used between structured data

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to determine correlation between two structured data sets.

Eg:

```
  D1
name: ABC
age: 3
address: xyz

  D2
name: ABC
dob: x/t/r
occupation: xyz
```

Is there a way to use Pearson correlation on structured data instead of variables?

Comment: This is more appropriate for [stats.se].

Comment: What properties do you want the measure of correlation to have?  What do you want to use it for?  If I propose a possible measure, how do you plan to evaluate it?  What criteria will you use?  (Note that cross-posting is not allowed, so please don't post the same question on Cross Validated unless you delete this copy first.)

Answer (score 1):

No. Pearson's correlation is a correlation measure between two variables. You might be looking for `canonical correlation analysis`.